# ¿Como usar Django con una base de datos ya existente en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Tengo una aplicación en Django 2.0 y como motor de base de datos uso MySQL. Tengo un inconveniente ya que la base de datos estaba creada previamente y ya cuenta con registros, mi idea es usar esta misma base de datos para la aplicación que estoy creando.

Use el comando

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Para crear el archivo models.py el cual limpie tal como lo indica el propio archivo models.py que se genero.

```
# Este es un módulo de modelo de Django generado automáticamente.
# Tendrás que hacer lo siguiente manualmente para limpiar esto:
# * Reordenar el orden de los modelos
# * Asegúrese de que cada modelo tenga un campo con primary_key = True
# * Asegúrese de que cada ForeignKey tenga `on_delete` establecido en el comportamiento deseado.
# * Elimine las líneas `managed = False` si desea permitir que Django cree, modifique y elimine la tabla
# Siéntase libre de cambiar el nombre de los modelos, pero no cambie el nombre de los valores de db_table o los nombres de campo.
```

Después de esto procedo a ejecutar:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Pero me genera el siguiente error:

```
(1050, "Table 'XXXXXXX' already exists")
```

Evidentemente me indica que la tabla ya existe, pero como hago para que no genere este error y seguir administrando las tablas desde Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes integrar tu base datos existente con los siguentes pasos, aunque ya los hayas hecho pero de esta forma me ha funcionado:

1. Crea un proyecto `Django` ejecutando `django-admin.py` `startproject myapp` (donde myapp es el nombre de tu aplicación).
2. Edita el archivo de configuración en ese proyecto, `mysite/settings.py`, para decirle a `Django` cuáles son los parámetros de conexión a tu base de datos y cuál es su nombre. Específicamente, provee las **configuraciones de**:

> DATABASE_NAME,DATABASE_ENGINE, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_HOST, y DATABASE_PORT.

4. Crea una aplicación dentro de tu proyecto ejecutando `python mysite/manage.py` `startapp myapp` (donde myapp es el nombre de tu aplicación).
5. Ejecuta el comando `python mysite/manage.py inspectdb`. Esto examinará las tablas en la base de datos `DATABASE_NAME` e imprimirá para cada tabla el modelo de clase generado. Hecha una mirada a la salida para tener una idea de lo que puede hacer inspectdb.
6. Guarda la salida en el archivo `models.py` dentro de tu aplicación usando la redirección de salida estándar de la shell:

   ```
   $ python mysite/manage.py inspectdb > mysite/myapp/models.py
   ```

Para el error que te esta dando puedes usar este codigo para que marque las migraciones como ejecutadas sin realmente ejecutarlas.

> (1050, "Table 'XXXXXXX' already exists")

Usa el siguente comando:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake <el nombre del proyecto>
```

o puedes usar este comando:

```
python manage.py help migrate
```

Puedes leer mas sobre este error en este link [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south)

Comment: Es lo que he hecho el problema esta cuando quiero realizar una migracion que genera el error descrito en la pregunta

Comment: Ya hicieste el paso 6?

Comment: Ya es cuando me genera el models.py y en cual indica la limpieza que se debe hacer

Comment: @jhon1946 Edita la respuesta prueba con el comando que te envie